# What is the correct path to call a ASP.net controller method from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, json

Perhaps because some things in ASP.net work automagically, I can't seem to access a method in a controller from JavaScript properly. It keeps saying the resource is not found.
[image: Error Message]

I have a JS file in `/Scripts/Wizards/wizard.js`

```
function GetSum()
{
    $.get("/Infrastructure/Base/GetJsonEcatalogs/");
    return false;
}
GetSum();
```

The controller I am trying to reference is the BaseController in `/Infrastructure/BaseController.cs` which has the method:

```
public String GetJsonEcatalogs()
    {
        // ...
        return jsonString
    }
```

The method returns a JSON-formatted string which I need to use later in the JavaScript. I don't necessarily have to use `$.get` if it is not necessary, I just thought that would be easiest (should I use **AJAX**?).

How can I get the JSON string from this controller?

Comment: Does BaseController derive from `Controller`? Do you have a virtual application path? Are you calling this from inside an area? Can you edit the exact exception message with stacktrace into your question? Have you tried disabling the javascript cache  for `get`, because the result could be a cached result.

Comment: @Silvermind This is the `BaseController` that is auto generated when you create an ASP.net MVC application (it calls the layout pages). Yes it inherits from Controller. I don't know what you mean by "calling from inside an area" and I'm 99% sure it is not a caching issue

Comment: Where did the `Infrastructure` part of the URL come from. Is this an MVC Area?

Comment: Ah, I see. It is just the folder that the `BaseController` is in. In Solution Explorer you have `<ProjectRoot>/Infrastructure/BaseController.cs` as the file path.